# Jenkins security II - Deny anonymous access but allow access via CLI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I previously asked how to get Jenkins to deny anonymous read access here: [Jenkins security - hide all screens unless user is logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226681/jenkins-security-hide-all-screens-unless-user-is-logged-in).  That solution worked great, except that it broke access to Jenkins via the CLI jar, despite the fact that we're using the CLI via an SSH key associated with a user - I guess that access doesn't constitute an "authentication".  Is there a way to get the CLI to have read access, but not users using the front-end UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more experimentation, this looks to be a flat-out Jenkins bug - granting the Anonymous user Administrative rights is necessary to make access via the cli jar (with an SSH key) or via HTTP (with the user's API token) work.

Comment: Don't know why my own answer is downvoted, when no one has suggested anything that actually works, but whatever.

Comment: Happy to report that this is fixed since then (https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8815).

Comment: Very happy to hear that I wasn't crazy and that the bug is fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using the CLI, you can pass `-jnlpCredentials` or `-auth` parameter.

Found it through trial an error using this:
`java -jar slave.jar --help`

In your case, you'd use the `-auth` parameter to specify `username:pass`

Comment: I guess I could try that, and see whether Jenkins treats that means of authentication differently from authorization via ssh key.

Comment: Finally got around to trying that, and it didn't work.  Apparently newer jenkins has done away with the auth parameter and only accepts an SSH key, which I'm using successfully modulo this apparent Jenkins bug.